# How to load YouTube API locally?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I need to load the YouTube API locally (Google Extension not allowing external scripts).  So I downloaded the files into my directory:

```
https://www.youtube.com/player_api
https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl4qCmf3.js
```

However, when I try to programmatically inject this via a content script, it gives the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: YTConfig is not defined
```

Comment: In a content script, or within an extensions page?

Comment: In a content script.  I use a content script to append a YT video at the bottom of the page.  Now I want to use load the YT library in the content script to control it.

Comment: That's going to be a bit difficult because the YT API uses `<script>` tags to load dependencies. You could either check which dependencies are needed, and include them in your extension, or use https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext.

Comment: Yeah, I dug through the code and it seems like those are the only two files needed.  Which is weird because YTConfig is defined in the second file.  I'm not sure why it's displaying YTConfig is not defined.  Maybe I'm loading it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To the OP: You were almost there! I'd like to acknowledge Jonathan Waldman, MSDN author, for mentioning this technique during one of his training sessions...

To review, YTConfig is defined at:

http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api

And here:

http://www.youtube.com/player_api

The iframe_api is the preferred link to use.

To recap, the links you provide above each link to JS code:

https://www.youtube.com/player_api

https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl4qCmf3.js

You also need a Div tag with an id of "player" and another Script tag that lets you specify which video you want to see. So there are four Script tags total:

1. For content in iframe_api
2. For content at https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl4qCmf3.js
3. For the player Div tag:

   ```
   <div id="player"></div>
   ```
4. For JavaScript that configures the video

This translates loosely to:

```
<script>...place the player Div here</script>
<script>...place code from www-widgetapi-vfl4qCmf3.js here...</script>
<script>...place code from iframe_api here...</script>
<script>...place the code below here</script>
```

Here is the code for the final Script tag (note that you will likely want to change the videoId property so that it points to the ID of the desired video on the YouTube site):

```
<script>
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

When I did the above, the page worked and I had all of the YouTube code local to my development machine.